# Import Java class from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I understand how to push a class to Firebase using the following code:

```
WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();        
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.child("Events").push().setValue(event);
```

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to retrieve this class (or any other class based on an id, or field) back into Android? I'm sure there's an easy way, but all I've found so far is the following which doesn't work:

```
    public void importSchedule(String ownerName){
    DatabaseReference events = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events");

    Query allOwnersEvents = events.equalTo(ownerName);

    allOwnersEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                WeekViewEvent allDay = post.child(WeekViewEvent.class); // This doesn't compile, as the type needs to be String
            }
        }
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

The WeekViewEvent objects have the following variables:

```
public class WeekViewEvent {
    private long mId;
    private Calendar mStartTime;
    private Calendar mEndTime;
    private String mName;
    private String mLocation;
    private int mColor;
    private boolean mAllDay;
    private String owner;

    //setters and getters
}
```

and in my Firebase, the object I'm trying to query is:

```
Events{
 -siX1hB9k-HpCmfO3n:{
    allDay:"false",
    color:"-477870",
    endTime:{
      endHour:4,
      endMinute:10,
      ...},
    id: 1,
    location:"location",
    name: "hi",
    owner: "a@a.ca",
    startTime:{
      startHour:3,
      startMinute:45,
      ...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`.getValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class<T>)) instead of `.child()`?

Comment: `.getChildren()` returns an iterative list of Children that match the query - to the best of my understanding. When I replaced it with `.getValue()` it let me know foreach is not available for.type java.lang.object

Comment: Hi Tyler. Sorry if my comment was confusing. I actually meant for you to replace the `.child()` with `.getValue()` *inside the for loop*. Not the `.getChildren()`. Try it out and let me know if something changes. Cheers!

Comment: `.getValue()` seems to compile in the loop, however when I place a debugger on it, it never seems to get called. Maybe I'm using the `addValueEventListner()` incorrectly? I've added a `sched.addEventToSchedule(allDay);` underneath the .getValue() statement, as that's all I'm really trying to do: get the object I've pushed and put it in this array of "events". Maybe I should just grab all the objects and sort through them on the app side? I don't mind going the hard way, as long as I can get it to return an object with the matching fields. Thanks for your help by the way! :)

Comment: Hmmm. I think I'm missing something here. Could you post your `WeekViewEvent` class and a sample of your database structure? You're welcome btw. :)

Comment: I think it may be an issue with the Query, or EventListener - as my debugger doesn't hit any of the breakpoints inside of the `.onDataChange()`

Comment: I see. I would suggest to see what's not triggering `onDataChange()`. Maybe try adding data from the console while the app is running?

Comment: `getValue(WeekView.class)` should work and compile. You can't have Calendar objects, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix t his, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference myNewRef = myRef.child("Events").push();
String pushedKey = myNewRef.getKey();
myNewRef.setValue(event);
```

and to get the data back:

```
public void importSchedule(String ownerName){

    DatabaseReference events = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child(pushedKey);
    Query allOwnersEvents = events.equalTo(ownerName);

    allOwnersEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String allDay = post.child("yourFiedName").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

In which `yourFiedName` is the name of desired field. Hope it helps.

Comment: I got an Incompatible types error on the first block: Required: database.DatabaseReference Found: android.gms.tasks.Task

Comment: Why pick out individual fields instead of whole objects?

Comment: When you `query` in that way, the type of the element that is found is of type `String` and not `WeekViewEvent`. So in order to solve this problem, you need to use the `String` class. Because that's the way Firebase works. You need to get down on the tree to desired location.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following method to retrieve your class' object

```
Map<String, Object> eventMap;
for(DataSnapshot da :dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
    if (da.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        eventMap = (HashMap<String, Object>)
                da.getValue();
        Map<String, Object> eventMap = weekMap;
        WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this put the data back into the class if you're creating a new object? `(WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();)` is the data stored in `Map<String, Object> messageMap = eventMap;`?

Comment: event.setDay((String) eventMap.get("day"));

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense - I went to run a debugger and it's not hitting the breakpoints inside the EventListener, so I'm unable to see if it is properly grabbing the Map. Maybe my query isn't grabbing anything?

Comment: If there is a POJO to deserialize to, that's preferable over a Map